# Phusion Passenger and Docker-Compose Issue with Permissions

Tags: docker, passenger, docker-compose

I am encountering a permissions issue when running `docker-compose` and Phusion Passenger's `docker` image.

Specifically, the error is: 
`Permission denied @ rb_sysopen - /var/www/my_app/tmp/.....`

My `docker-compose.yml` file contains the following information:

```
happy_passenger:
  build: .
  container_name: happy_passenger
  ports:
    - "80:80"
  volumes:
    - .:/var/www/my_app
  links:
   - redis
redis:
  container_name: my_redis
  image: redis
  ports:
    - "6379:6379"
```

When running `docker-compose up`, the application loads, but then I am met with the `Permission denied @ rb_sysopen` error.

---

My `Dockerfile` is relatively straight-forward too:

```
# Dockerfile

FROM phusion/passenger-ruby21:0.9.17
MAINTAINER meoww- "none@none.com"

# Set correct environment variables.
ENV HOME /root

# Initialize "in production"
ENV RAILS_ENV production

# Use baseimage-docker's init process.
CMD ["/sbin/my_init"]

# Turn on Nginx
RUN rm -f /etc/service/nginx/down

# Remove the default site that comes with Nginx
RUN rm /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default

ADD nginx.conf /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/my_app.conf

WORKDIR /tmp
ADD Gemfile /tmp/
ADD Gemfile.lock /tmp/
RUN bundle install

ADD . /var/www/my_app
RUN chown -R app:app /var/www/my_app

# Clean up APT when done.
RUN apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/*
```

---

### Troubleshooting

1. When I modify my `docker-compose.yml` file and remove the `volumes:` block, I am able to view my application. Unfortunately, if I don't have a `volumes:` block, then I am required to rebuild the docker image after every code change that I make. So that option will not work.
2. I noticed that when the application starts, I'm seeing a permissions error too:

`App 66 stderr: Rails Error: Unable to access log file. Please ensure that /var/www/my_app/log/development.log exists and is writable (ie, make it writable for user and group: chmod 0664 /var/www/my_app/log/development.log)`

Per the error above (#2), I tried adding a `RUN chmod -R 0664 /var/www/my_app` to my `Dockerfile` and removing + rebuilding everything (e.g. `docker rmi [image]`, then `docker-compose up` which rebuilt my image). This didn't seem to have any impact on this issue.

---

At this point, I'm inclined to think that there's something wrong with the way I'm setting up the `docker-compose` read-write permissions, but I am not finding any clear documentation on what I need to change.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears that the issue is a bug with boot2docker and how it mounts volumes on OSX. First, I ran the command `docker inspect happy_passenger`. This gave me the following information about my volume:

```
"Mounts": [
    {
        "Source": "/Users/meow/test/www/demodocker",
        "Destination": "/var/www/my_app",
        "Mode": "rw",
        "RW": true
    }
],
```

The volume was showing up in docker as Read/Write (R/W) enabled. Under normal circumstances, this would indicate that I should be able to use a mounted volume and write to the file system. However, since a bug exists with the R/W permissions, I was encountering various errors due to the fact that the permissions were wrong. Even running `chmod -R 777 .` on the shared and host directories **did not fix the issue**

To fix this, I did the following:

In my `dockerfile`

```
# Dockerfile

FROM phusion/passenger-ruby21:0.9.17
MAINTAINER meoww- "none@none.com"

# Hack to get around the boot2docker issue.
RUN usermod -u 1000 app
RUN usermod -G staff app
```

After adding the two commands `RUN usermod -u 1000 app` and `RUN usermod -G staff app` I was able to successfully load up my containerized application when using `docker-compose up`.

Hope this helps someone fix their docker permission errors/docker mounted volume bug.

Also, here's a link to the issue in Github:

https://github.com/boot2docker/boot2docker/issues/581